# GTFS MySQL Query Column Not Found

Tags: php, mysql, gtfs

Im working with GTFS dataset that I have imported into MySql, Im accessing it with PHP.
Im trying to find the trips for a specific route for a given time and date.
My Sql query looks like this

```
'SELECT  t.route_id AS route_id, t.service_id AS service_id, t.trip_headsign AS trip_headsign,
                t.trip_id AS trip_id,
              ( SELECT   departure_time
                FROM     stop_times
                WHERE    trip_id = t.trip_id
                ORDER BY departure_time ASC limit 1) AS initial_departure_time,
              ( SELECT   arrival_time
                FROM     stop_times
                WHERE    trip_id = t.trip_id
                ORDER BY arrival_time DESC limit 1) AS final_arrival_time
        FROM trips AS t INNER JOIN calendar_dates AS c
        WHERE t.service_id = c.service_id
          AND c.date ='.$calendar_date.' 
          AND initial_departure_time <='.$time.'
          AND'.$time. '<=final_arrival_time
          AND t.route_id ='.$route.'
        ORDER BY trip_id ASC';
```

`$route`, `$calendar_date` and `$time` are all passed in.

The query is returning Column not found:

> 1054 Unknown column 'initial_departure_time' in 'where clause'. Im thinking that initial_departure_time cant be evaluated.

Im completely lost as too how to resolve this. Any clues, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use aliases in your WHERE clause.

Either incorporate the sub-queries into the WHERE clause:

```
'SELECT t.route_id AS route_id, 
        t.service_id AS service_id, 
        t.trip_headsign AS trip_headsign,
        t.trip_id AS trip_id,
        (SELECT departure_time
         FROM stop_times
         WHERE trip_id = t.trip_id
         ORDER BY departure_time ASC limit 1) AS initial_departure_time,
        (SELECT arrival_time
         FROM stop_times
         WHERE trip_id = t.trip_id
         ORDER BY arrival_time DESC limit 1) AS final_arrival_time
FROM trips AS t INNER JOIN calendar_dates AS c
WHERE t.service_id = c.service_id
AND c.date ='.$calendar_date.' 
AND (SELECT departure_time
     FROM stop_times
     WHERE trip_id = t.trip_id
     ORDER BY departure_time ASC limit 1) <='.$time.'
AND'.$time. '<= (SELECT arrival_time
                 FROM stop_times
                 WHERE trip_id = t.trip_id
                 ORDER BY arrival_time DESC limit 1)
AND t.route_id ='.$route.'
ORDER BY trip_id ASC';
```

Or wrap the query and then use the aliases in that:

```
'SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT t.route_id AS route_id, 
        t.service_id AS service_id, 
        t.trip_headsign AS trip_headsign,
        t.trip_id AS trip_id,
        (SELECT departure_time
         FROM stop_times
         WHERE trip_id = t.trip_id
         ORDER BY departure_time ASC limit 1) AS initial_departure_time,
        (SELECT arrival_time
         FROM stop_times
         WHERE trip_id = t.trip_id
         ORDER BY arrival_time DESC limit 1) AS final_arrival_time
         FROM trips AS t INNER JOIN calendar_dates AS c
         WHERE t.service_id = c.service_id
         AND c.date ='.$calendar_date.' 
         AND t.route_id ='.$route.'
         ORDER BY trip_id ASC) a 
WHERE a.initial_departure_time <='.$time.'
AND'.$time. '<= a.final_arrival_time';
```

This might speed it up (you may need to swap the `MIN` and `MAX` around):

```
'SELECT t.route_id AS route_id, 
        t.service_id AS service_id, 
        t.trip_headsign AS trip_headsign,
        t.trip_id AS trip_id,
        MIN(s.departure_time) AS initial_departure_time,
        MAX(s.arrival_time) AS final_arrival_time
FROM trips AS t 
INNER JOIN calendar_dates AS c ON t.service_id = c.service_id
LEFT JOIN stop_times s ON s.trip_id = t.trip_id
WHERE c.date ='.$calendar_date.' 
AND t.route_id ='.$route.'
GROUP BY t.route_id, t.service_id, t.trip_headsign, t.trip_id,
HAVING '.$time.' BETWEEN MAX(s.arrival_time) AND MIN(s.departure_time)
ORDER BY trip_id ASC';
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks is there a way to make this call more efficient, the stop_times table is a monster. I have already created indexes which has helped.

Comment: @BrianSimms Try the third query I have added. You may need to swap the `MIN` and `MAX` around.